# Pass an image from Android via JavaScript interface to HTML (WebView)

Tags: javascript, android, bitmap

I'm trying to show an image in my HTML file. The image is loaded by Android and stored in SQLite. How can I pass an image (Bitmap) to HTML via AndroidInterface? and what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to save the image to a storage folder then refresh the page within the web component to show the image.

I'm using this approach to show a contextual help for my app. The html pages and images are stored inside a sqlite database.

I'm using `WebView`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

If you you have a bitmap which saved as a file then you can pass local file path to javascript.
You have to set "setDomStorageEnabled" of WebView as True

```
        <!-- language: lang-java -->
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        for(...){
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                object.put("img", "LOCAL_IMAGE_SRC_PATH");
                object.put("name", nameString);
                list.put(i++, object);
            } catch (JSONException e) {}
        }

        if(mWebView!=null){
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:addList('" + list + "');");
        }
```

```js
function addContactItem(src, name){
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    p.innerHTML = name;
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("src", src);
    img.setAttribute("width", "100");
    img.setAttribute("height", "100");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "Your image here");

    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    li.appendChild(img);
    li.appendChild(p);

    document.getElementById('contact_list').appendChild(li);
};

function addList(list){
    var myList = JSON.parse(list);
    for(var i=0; i<myList.length; i++){
        console.log("img: " + myList[i].img + " name: " + myList[i].name);
        addItem(myList[i].img, myList[i].name);
    }
};
```